# fxcop not running on .net core project when run from console

Tags: .net-core, roslyn, fxcop, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to integrate static analysis on a .net core 1.1 project. What I did until now is install the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers nuget and added the rules in the csproj under property group:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>../StaticAnalysis/ManagedRuleSet.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've created a rule violation to test, and the setup works well in Visual Studio 2017. The problem comes when I try to build from the console:

```
dotnet build
```

No errors or warnings :( This is crucial to get so I can make this run on the build machine as well.